# Binding function to element after adding it to DOM - AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, frameworks

I'm building small shop app in AngularJS. 
I'm adding products to the basket in directive like this:

```
app.directive('cart', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    controller: 'CartController',
    templateUrl: '/templates/cart.html',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) { 
      scope.add_product_to_cart = function (id) {
        //show cart element
        if (document.getElementsByClassName('cart')[0].style.display == "")
          document.getElementsByClassName('cart')[0].style.display = "block";
        //find products that match id
        for (var i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
          if (products[i].productId == id) {
            //check if product is already in cart
            var product_in_cart = false;
            for (var j = 0; j < scope.products.length; j++) {
              if (scope.products[j].productId == id) {
                product_in_cart = j;
                break;
              }
            }
            if (product_in_cart === false) {
              scope.products.push({
                productId: products[i].productId,
                title: products[i].title,
                price: products[i].price,
                imageUrl: products[i].imageUrl,
                categoryId: products[i].categoryId,
                count: 1
              }); 
            } else
              scope.products[j].count++;

          }
        }
      }

      scope.delete_product = function (id) {
        for (var i = 0; i < scope.products.length; i++) {
          if (id == scope.products[i].productId) {
            if (scope.products[i].count == 1) {
              scope.products.splice(i, 1);    
            } else {
              scope.products.count -= 1;  
            }
          }
        }   
      }

    }
  };
});
```

I can't execute `scope.delete_product` function, because it gives me "Error: [$parse:syntax]" error.

My template looks like this:
`<span class="cart-delete-product" ng-click="delete_product({{ product.productId }})">{{ delete_product }}</span>`

How can I bind `scope.delete_product` to element after DOM updates?

Comment: `ng-click` already takes an expression, so just use `delete_product(product.productId)`

Comment: Now it gives `TypeError: v2.delete_product is not a function` error.